# Haproxy multiple backend servers & ports

Tags: haproxy

I am a newbie to haproxy and was wondering if someone can confirm that the following config is valid?  Effectively I would like to load balanced two servers on multiple ports.

```
<snippet>
Listen mybackendLB
  bind 10.6.200.14:555,10.6.200.14:8009,10.6.200.14:443
  mode tcp
  balance roundrobin
  option httpchk "/test.html"
  server app1 192.168.0.20:555 check port 8008
  server app1 192.168.0.20:8009 check port 8008
  server app1 192.168.0.20:443 check port 8008
  server app2 192.168.0.21:555 check port 8008
  server app2 192.168.0.21:8009 check port 8008
  server app2 192.168.0.21:443 check port 8008
<snippet>
```

In any case would this be a better option?

```
<snippet>
Listen mybackendLB
  bind 10.6.200.14:555,10.6.200.14:8009,10.6.200.14:443
  mode tcp
  balance roundrobin
  option httpchk "/test.html"
  server app1 192.168.0.20 check port 8008
  server app2 192.168.0.21 check port 8008
<snippet>
```

Comment: The best way to ensure that the traffic goes to the same port is to split the listener individually. In above example, I need to create separate listeners for each port with 2 servers underneath.  there will be a total of 3 separate listen entries.